# Eclipse giving "weird" error concerning opencv

Tags: c++, eclipse, opencv, compiler-errors

I am running ubuntu 12.04.
I have a c++ project that I wrote and compiled fine in Eclipse(the version before luna). I had some issues with my system and had to do a OS reinstall. Now I am using Eclipse luna and the project gives a strange error when using some of the openCV functionality.

The errors I am having occur when I use the `cv::namedWindow()` and the `cv::imshow()`.
Errors are:

Here is eclipse console output:

```
00:21:45 **** Incremental Build of configuration Debug for project MySOM ****
make all 
Building target: MySOM
Invoking: Cross G++ Linker
g++ -L/usr/local/lib -o "MySOM"  ./src/LoadFile.o ./src/Model.o ./src/Node.o ./src/SOM.o ./src/main.o   -lopencv_calib3d -lopencv_contrib -lopencv_core -lopencv_features2d -lopencv_flann -lopencv_gpu -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_legacy -lopencv_ml -lopencv_nonfree -lopencv_objdetect -lopencv_ocl -lopencv_photo -lopencv_stitching -lopencv_superres -lopencv_ts -lopencv_video -lopencv_videostab
Finished building target: MySOM


00:21:45 Build Finished (took 210ms)
```

It looks find above but then...

Here is the Problems tab in eclipse:

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type

Invalid arguments '
Candidates are:
bool imwrite(const ? &, const cv::_InputArray &, const ? &)
'   SOM.cpp /MySOM/src  line 211    Semantic Error

Invalid arguments '
Candidates are:
cv::Mat imread(const ? &, int)
'   LoadFile.cpp    /MySOM/src  line 10 Semantic Error

Invalid arguments '
Candidates are:
void imshow(const ? &, const cv::_InputArray &)
'   main.cpp    /MySOM/src  line 22 Semantic Error

Invalid arguments '
Candidates are:
void namedWindow(const ? &, int)
'   main.cpp    /MySOM/src  line 21 Semantic Error
```

main.cpp

```
#include "Node.h"
#include <iostream>
#include "SOM.h"
#include <string>
#include "opencv2/core/core.hpp"
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>//FOR TESTING



void MyPause(std::string msg){
    if(msg != ""){
        std::cout << "[+] " << msg << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << "Press enter to continue" << std::endl;
    std::cin.get();
}

void DisplayMat(cv::Mat img){
    static int number = 0;
    cv::namedWindow( "Input" + number, cv::WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );// ERROR HERE
    cv::imshow( "Input" + number, img );//ERROR HERE
    cv::waitKey(0);
    number++;
    return;
}


std::string filename = "/home/myUserName/Code/projectFiles/testMedia/myYellow.jpg";


int main(){

    //cv::Mat inputImg = LoadFile(filename);

    SOM som(filename);
    MyPause("After SOM initialization");
    DisplayMat(som.inputImg);

    MyPause("END OF MAIN");
    return 0;
}
```

I wonder if this could be occurring because of how I compiled opencv now compared to how i compiled it on my original system.

Comment: did you find what is going on? I had exactly the same problem. Lots of strange errors. No matter how many time I rebuilt it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had tried refreshing, cleaning, and rebuilding 3 times before doing this but it seems that after posting I tried a fourth just to be sure and behold it has worked.

Answer (score 2):

This keeps happening to me when I upgrade the eclipse. It has all the strange error of `Member declaration not found`, `invalid overload of endl`, `Invalid arguments ...`, Now I figured out that it is the info in the workspace and old projects were not up-to-date for the new CDT codan. It is actually very easy to solve this problem: `Project->C/C++ index->Rebuild`. After it is done, all strange errors will go away.

Answer (score 1):

This expression is not valid: `"Input" + number`. You can't just concatenate string literals with numbers. Well you can but the result will not be what you expect.

Fortunately you are programming C++, which means you can use [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) and [`std::to_string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string) (if you have a C++11 compatible compiler): `std::string("Input") + std::to_string(number)`.

If you don't have C++11, and therefore not `std::to_string`, then you can use e.g. [the Boost lexical cast library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/doc/html/boost_lexical_cast.html), or [`std::istringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istringstream) to format the string, or other formatting functions/libraries.